# mathematica for game of life rule b25/s4

Tags: cellular-automata

I have the Mathematica code below to show the game of life rule B3/S23, can you please tell me how I can change it in order to show rule B25/s4 ?

```
GameOfLife = {224, {2, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}, {1, 1}};
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[GameOfLife, RandomInteger[1, {100, 100}], {{{100}}}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rules = <|"Dimension" -> 2, "GrowthSurvivalCases" -> {{2, 5}, {4}}|>;
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[rules, RandomInteger[1, {100, 100}], {{{100}}}]]
```